# 2 Different outputs (Chrome and IE/FIREFOX)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When i load the database value like this:

```
<?=$list[time]?>
```

In chrome the output is: 2013-10-07T14:27:56
In firefox the output is: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

How is this possible?? 
`$list[time]` is a timestamp value in the database.

MY CODE:

```
$lsel_list = mysql_query("select * from users WHERE id = '$id' order by id asc");
while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($lsel_list)) { 
  echo"$list[time]";
}
```

field time is timestamp in database with a time. (2013-10-07 14:28:35)

Comment: Show us your actual code

Comment: without code how can we help?

Comment: most probably you are supplying an invalid id when you call it with firefox. the browser has no impact on the PHP output.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this :
echo date("Y m d",strtotime($list[time]));
```

Comment: its also with seconds, and hours does that matter?